# Create document library with look up and multi line text box feilds using powershell

Tags: document-library, powershell, column

Create document library with look up and multi-line text box fields using the below PowerShell

```
Remove-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

#To which site u want to create the list 
$spWeb=Get-SPWeb -Identity http://xyz

#List type or template 

$spTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary 

#Get all the lists to the listcollection
$spListCollection=$spWeb.Lists

#adding the new list to the list collection
$spListCollection.Add("Student1","Student1",$spTemplate)

#get the path of subsite and sitecollecion 
$path = $spWeb.url.trim()

#get the list to the list object
$spList = $spWeb.Lists["Student1"]

#adding the field type(Note) to the list
$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Note
$spList.Fields.Add("COMMENTS",$spFieldType,$false)

$ParentList = $spWeb.Lists.item("Studentlist")
$spList = $spWeb.Lists["Student1"]
$spList.Fields.AddLookup("lookupcol",$ParentList.id,$true)
$spChildListLookupField = $spList.Fields["lookupcol"]
$spChildListLookupField.LookupField = $ParentList.Fields["ID"]
$spChildListLookupField.Indexed = $true
$spChildListLookupField.RelationshipDeleteBehavior = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRelationshipDeleteBehavior]::Restrict
$spChildListLookupField.Update()


$Views = $spList.Views["All Items"]
$Views.ViewFields.Add("COMMENTS")
$Views.ViewFields.Add("lookupcol")


$Views.Update()

$spWeb.Dispose()
```

I am getting errors -

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression - $spList.Fields.Add("COMMENTS",$spFieldType,$false)

Comment: Make sure the list got created before adding fields.

Comment: I added 
$spList = $spWeb.Lists["Student1"]
$spList.update() - so now the list is getting created and columns are added. but i am getting error at viewfeilds - You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
+ $Views.ViewFields.Add("COMMENTS")

Comment: Ok now the view is fine. I changed from $Views = $spList.Views["All Items"] to $Views = $spList.Views["All Documents"] - Thanks !